# Differentiate $\theta^TX^TX\theta$ with respect to $\theta$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, vectors

I have a matrix $X$ and a vector $\theta$ and I wish to differentiate the expression $\theta^TX^TX\theta$ with respect to $\theta$. Is is correct to assume the following?

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}(\theta^TX^TX\theta) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta}(X^TX\theta\theta^T) = 2X^TX\theta $$

I cannot think of any other way to solve this; however, I am not sure if the commutation I made is allowed in this context.

Answer (score 0):

People often underestimate the trivial ways. In this case, setting $X^T X = Y,$ the thing you are differentiating equals $\sum_{i, j} Y_{ij} \theta_i \theta_j,$ which is a quadratic function in the $\theta$s and trivial to differentiate (the gradient equals $2 Y \theta$).